# Check balanced brackets

Tags: clojure

<sup>Yes, I know we have a lot of these.</sup>

I'm new to Clojure, but not to lisps. After the recent (javascript?) parentheses-balancing Q, I decided to do an implementation in Clojure for practice with the language. (It also *happened* to make a nice accompaniment to my rant about students learning what is and isn't possible with regular expressions.)

I chose to use `(reduce)` over recursion mostly because I am a fan of letting functions do the work of creating loops and recursion for me, but in this case I am not sure how "elegant" I consider the `:false` handling.

#### [Code](https://gist.github.com/benknoble/f6d157217a7a814450d6fc9cf45625ee)

```clj
(ns parens)

(def str->chars (partial map identity))

(defn mk-balanced?
  "makes a balanced? checker from table, which maps closing characters to
  opening characters.

  see also: balanced?"
  [table]
  (fn [s]
    (let [opens (set (vals table))
          closes (set (keys table))]
      (empty?
        (reduce
          (fn [stack cur]
            (if (not= (peek stack) :false)
              (condp contains? cur
                opens (conj stack cur)
                closes (if (and (seq stack)
                                (= (peek stack) (table cur)))
                         (pop stack)
                         [:false])
                stack)
              [:false]))
          []
          (str->chars s))))))

(def balanced?
  (mk-balanced? {\) \(
                 \] \[
                 \} \{}))
```

Comment: For `str->chars` just use `(vec some-str)`.

Comment: @AlanThompson `(seq s)` is nicer to me, but thanks, that was helpful to learn (I was frustrated not to find an idiomatic version of it on my own!)

Answer (score 3):

I'd never thought of using `reduce` for this. Neat! However, you can simplify `mk-balanced?` a little.

- `str->chars` is redundant: `reduce` and the other sequence functions accept strings as such.
- You can use [`reduced`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduced) to short circuit a `reduce`.
- The `reduced` can return any non-empty sequence: no need for `[:false]`.

The simplified version is ...

```
(defn mk-balanced? [table]
  (fn [s]
    (let [opens (set (vals table))
          closes (set (keys table))]
      (empty?
        (reduce
          (fn [stack cur]
            (condp contains? cur
              opens (conj stack cur)
              closes (if (and (seq stack)
                              (= (peek stack) (table cur)))
                       (pop stack)
                       (reduced [nil]))
              stack))
          []
          s)))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments :) I actually updated the gist (linked in the Q) several days ago with this approach when I discovered reduced.

Comment: I missed your gist. it's OK around here to answer your own question. However, I enjoyed your code. First convincing example of `condp` I've seen.